# How to proxy pass DirectAdmin in shared hosting from nginx in VPS

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, web-hosting, proxypass, directadmin

- I have a subdomain `da.myvps.com` pointing to my VPS IP with nginx installed.
- I have a shared hosting with DirectAdmin URL `https://mysharedhosting:2222/evo/`.
- I want to access my DirectAdmin with my subdomain using nginx proxy pass with the following config below, so I can access the DirectAdmin by going to this URL: `https://da.myvps.com/evo/` instead of `https://mysharedhosting:2222/evo/`.

```bash
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name da.myvps.com;

  location /evo/ {
    proxy_pass https://mysharedhosting.com:2222/evo/;
  }

  location = / {
    return 301 https://da.myvps.com/evo/;
  }

  # This endpoint is used by DirectAdmin to get data
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass https://mysharedhosting.com:2222/evo/api/;
  }
}
```

I can access the web but it displaying this error below:
[image: DirectAdmin error]

Do you have any idea how to fix it? Is it possible to do that? Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot!